# Charge and power distribution circuit with multiple batteries

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, lithium-ion, charger

I’m looking for solution for electric vehicle charge and power distribution system PCB. 
For some reasons I want to split battery to several Li-Ion packs in separated units (hulls). I see the next possible setup for me, as shown in the Fig. 1 below.

[image: Fig 1. Functional Block Diagram for Charge and power distribution system]

The main question for me is the realization of such kind of “parallel” connections of chargers and power sharing between battery units and System Load. Is this a right way for such setup? I’m understand that batteries will try to equalize voltage between the units, but it is acceptable for me.
I want to use one of the Analog Devices (or another) charger IC’s and connect several chargers like as shown on Fig. 2 below. What could go wrong?

[image: Fig 2. Charger Unit (example schematic from Analog Devices LTC4008-1 datasheet)]

Also maybe there are similar on-the-shelf solutions or best ways?

Comment: re " I’m understand that batteries will try to equalize voltage between the units, but it is acceptable for me" -> It may be acceptable to you but, worst case, the batteries will add magic smoke, vent with flame and destruction. Due care is needed when parallellingh batteries that they are within suitable voltages AND that worst case current flows are both designed and allowed for. || Q: "What could go wrong?" A: "What could go wrong? !!! :-) !!!".

Comment: Providing a "datasheet link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4008.pdf) is always a good idea. || Why do you chain the next charger(s) past the current limit sense resistor? It's not obvious to me that that's good or useful.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for reply!

Comment: @RussellMcMahon
re "batteries will add magic smoke"
Ep, I'm understanding the problems of parallel battery connections and for this reason I want to separate it with discrete chargers, one charger per each Li-Ion bat pack.
Probably I misunderstood example schematic, but if I connect "System Load" of 1st charge circuit to "DCIN" of 2nd charge circuit that will give me separated battery packs which haven't direct connections between each other?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for datasheet link, I'm forget about it!
Well, I completely agree, that Rcl not necessary needed (I guess) for my case. This schematic above is a direct copy of example schematic from datasheet and needed only for idea demonstration (connect System Load to DCIN).

Comment: Shared voltage SMPS are inherently unstable without complex compensation to prevent offset  unbalance and burst ringing with resonance.  I remember PowerOne's rackmount failures like this fixed with 10% preload and 0.2% balance.  But  CC mode sharing is slow BW so the trick is to make a bus with exceptionally low ESR and ESL. and similar rated mOhm Caps. to result in high SRF (MHz)  There must be a global and local current sense for ratio metric sharing.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you much for detailed reply. I faced with it when tried to parallel some murata dc-dc for one university project :)
Whatever, there is any way to reach something like described on first picture?

Comment: Individual cell A,V,'C sensed is the best way with a serial port with BMS string control and parallel sharing for master CC level I think to optimize cell balance and life span.  But also pay attention to life extension with tradeoff for 10% capacity and reduced CV levels to 4.1 or 4.0 and raising LV warning thresholds to 25% SoC or even 50% and using 2x banks for twice the life but also get up to speed on battery characteristics from   https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/ultra_fast_chargers ,   https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/battery-capacity

Comment: Sorry I read too fast. your packs are isolated  No problem as long as demand does not exceed supply. including system load and battery I sense. Each BMS is self contained OK

Comment: for PV:  Buck boost regulator Zin input impedance MUST  match PV Zout = Vmp/Imp for MPT to  work. With 4 that's harder to do but possible with global IC-CC supply controlled from MPT controller then reduced by CV threshold.

Comment: Risks of parallel Tesla packs with BMS chargers (not recommended without as I described)  https://www.orionbms.com/manuals/pdf/tesla_modules.pdf  etc https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNSXA1SMPge8OZ16Tl2j_wE7-FtAUA%3A1571293299373&ei=cwioXYK7Fq-v_QadupHQCw&q=tesla+bms&oq=tesla+bms&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0l9.5285.5285..5641...0.0..0.107.107.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.Si7CWgM0mf4&ved=0ahUKEwjCwMnX06LlAhWvV98KHR1dBLoQ4dUDCAo&uact=5

Comment: on  the grid but unorthodox EE solutions  to Tesla chargers https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DVsTLEgVMAUDF-2.jpg  Fully configurable. 18p of 12s74p. 15,984 cells in 216 groups https://twitter.com/wk057/status/962384238631968769